# Querying for Unique Values When The Value Exists on Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, select

*Thank you for reading!*

I want to find any value ("**Name**"), but I don't want that value if it exists on the same row as a "**Type**" that equals "Z".

As an example, in the table below, I want all Sam and Joe records, but I do not want any Bob records, because one of the rows that Bob exists on, contains a "Z" value in the "Type" field. If any Bob has a "Z", I want none of the "Bobs"

| **Name** | **Type** |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | A |
| Bob | B |
| Bob | Z |
| Sam | A |
| Joe | A |
| Joe | B |
| Joe | C |

You may have guessed my problem by now. If I attempt to select the records based on the "**Type**" field *NOT* containing "Z", then I will still get back the two "Bob" rows that contain "A" and the "B".

If any of the bob rows contain "Z", I don't want *any* "Bob" rows to return. See desired results below:

| **Name** |
| --- |
| Sam |
| Joe |

Does anyone know how to achieve this in a SQL select statement?

Many thanks,

Logan

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result using the same format.

Comment: @jarlh, I'm not too savvy but I think we use IBM DB2.

Comment: @jarlh, I attempted to edit the post, adding in my desired results. The table was formatted correctly in the preview, but did not seem to come through when I submitted the edit.

Comment: You need an empty row before the table to get the table format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group the query by the `name` and have a `having` condition that counts the `type`s with the value "Z":

```sql
SELECT   name
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
HAVING   COUNT(CASE name WHEN 'Z' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Learning as I go here, please bear with me. How come the `name` is able to come before the `when` in the `count` clause?

Also, I am having trouble understanding the logic mechanics of the `count` = 0. If `count` = 1, then it doesn't pull the record, and if count is null, it does pull the record?

Thanks again for the response.

Comment: @LoganPrice there are a couple of things going on here. WRT `case` having an expression before the `when` - it's the shorter syntax. `name` is the expression being tested, and it's evaluated against a series of `when` clauses (one, in this instance). When `name` is `'Z'`, the case expression returns `1`. Implicitly, if none of the case `when` clauses are met, `null` is returned. The second "trick" here is that `count` has a neat trait of skipping nulls, so the entire `count` call actually counts how many `'Z'`s that name has. And the `having` condition returns the names with 0 such occurances.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! I understand it now. I got it to work by using the "long" syntax, (CASE WHEN name = 'Z' THEN 1 END) and the SQL results were exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.name
FROM MyTable t
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (
               SELECT 1
               FROM MyTable
               WHERE
               name = t.name
               AND type = 'Z'
)
```